# How to receive a push notification in PubNub Android ???

Tags: android, pubnub

What will be the broadcast receiver to receive a push notification in pubnub android.

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code for a broadcast receiver yet? I believe PubNub's GCM push notifications simply send a publish through PubNub protocol (no receiver required) and a push notification through the standard GCM protocol. It should look like a standard push notification receiver.

Comment: Then what should be the filter of that Receiver ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PubNub released a blog post that fully covers sending and receiving GCM with their Android SDK.

[Sending and Receiving Android Push Notifications w/ GCM](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/)

To summarize, the receiver and intent filter should look as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" > 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
        <category android:name="your.package.name" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver> 
<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" /> 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And your `GcmBroadcastReceiver` should look something like this:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName()); 
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp))); 
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK); 
    } 
}
```

And finally, the `GcmIntentService`:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {   
    public GcmIntentService() { 
        super("GcmIntentService"); 
    }   

    @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { 
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this); 
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);   
        if (!extras.isEmpty() && GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE) {
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString()); 
        } 
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent); 
    }
    ...
}
```

If there is anything that I am not covering that you wish to see, check the blog. If you do not see it there or are still having trouble let me know and I would be glad to elaborate on anything PubNub GCM related for you!